# Open Different Forms Depending Upon Installation Time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform app. I wanna open different windows form depending upon a condition during installation,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        if (something)
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Run(new Form2());
        }
    }
```

I am publishing my app using VS publish tab which generate a setup.exe file. Now I dont know what to pass setup.exe to get them in my Main method. I tried to run setup.exe using,

```
setup.exe MyParam=MyParam
setup.exe "MyParam=MyParam"
setup.exe "MyParam"
setup.exe MyParam
setup.exe /q "MyParam=MyParam"
and so on
```

and then in my Main method I tried,

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
```

which return null in every above case(I mean when I run setup.exe the Main method will be invoked).

Then I tried,

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

which include the path of the running exe(in temp folder). Then I tried,

```
args.Length
```

which returns 0. Then I created property,

```
public static string MyParam{ get; set; }
```

which always return null. So, my question is how can I pass arguments to setup.exe that will be carried to my application exe? I have no option other than running setup.exe because of company policy.

**Update:** For now I am using query string approach as given here, http://madskristensen.net/post/url-parameters-in-clickonce-applications

Comment: You publish using click-once (properties > publish > publish now)?

Comment: @Evk Yup `properties > publish > publish now`

Comment: I think you can't do what you want using ClickOnce. You'll probably need another installation system, as [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) or [InstallShield](https://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/)

Comment: Do you need the parameters when setup.exe executed? Or the application.exe executed?

Comment: @Berkay actually our admin team is asking for setup.exe and they want to execute setup.exe with additional params. Our application should take these params and decide upon these parameters what to do next.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible with clickonce. After setup it creates the application.exe into app_data, if you execute application file with parameters, you can read the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Running and installing your App are two totally different things.

When you start your App, you choose the form to display depending on 'something'. That's ok. But before, when you install the App by your Setup, the App is not started, so no possibility to pass 'something'.

I think you are talking about some configuration options, that are defined when installing your App and that are used when running the App later. So, may be your Setup can create a configuration file, that later can be used by your App.

Comment: The problem is that our operation team is insisting to give them a setup.exe file but we are unable to get arguments passed from setup.exe to our app.

Comment: I don't understand, how you deploy your app. Is it not this way: 1) You build your app and a setup file. 2) You give it to the user/admin. 3) The user/admin execute the setup file. 4) That will create the app file (and may be a config file). 5) The user runs the app. 6) The app reads the config.

Comment: Right but I wanna run setup file using command line. So, sometimes I need to pass arguments to setup.exe. For example, during installation(running setup.exe) for User1 I wanna show Form1 and for User2 I wanna show Form2. In short, I need some installation options that my app can read after installation.